# AMDGPU 5.5.1 + Mesa 23.2 possible?

Tags: amdgpu, mesa

Do you know of a way to change the Mesa version that comes with AMD's AMDGPU driver, or if that is even possible? I have a Radeon RX 7900 XTX card that I use as an eGPU for a Dell XPS 13 laptop running Ubuntu 23.04 with kernel version 6.3.

I originally only had the graphics drivers from Oibaf's PPA installed, which gave me Mesa 23.2.0-devel from Git, however performance was somewhat slow and unstable with my setup, for reasons I ignore. Therefore I installed AMD's AMDGPU packages through `amdgpu-install`, version 5.5.1, and the difference is breathtaking. Smooth playing of very recent games with "Ultra" graphics settings. I noticed though that the *OpenGL core profile version string* in `glxinfo` is *Mesa 23.1.0-devel*, not *Mesa 23.2.0-devel (git-a6a687b 2023-06-14 jammy-oibaf-ppa)*. So far nothing astounding, since the AMDGPU installer installs its own libraries.

My question is this: do you know of a way to use AMD's official AMDGPU driver *and* Oibaf's latest Git version of Mesa hand in hand, or rather to have AMDGPU use Oibaf's Mesa version, by removing some packages and installing others, changing configuration files, etc.?

**UPDATE:**

I think I see a little bit more clearly now. Oibaf's PPA really seems to have no bearing on the OpenGL core profile version as reported by `glxinfo`, as far as I can tell. The Mesa version remains the same. However, it does make a difference when it comes to Vulkan. `glxinfo` is mostly about OpenGL, if I understand correctly. `vulkaninfo`, before installing the Oibaf PPA, printed out the *driverInfo* of my eGPU which was *Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1*. Now, after installing the PPA, that line says *Mesa 23.3~git2307240600.06db9b~oibaf~l (git-06db9bd 2023-07-24 lunar-oibaf-ppa)*. So, AMDGPU 5.X.X and Mesa 23.X from Git *are* possible, but when using Vulkan, not when using OpenGL it would seem. Do not hesitate to correct my ignorance on many of these things!

Answer (score 0):

I had this setup until recently for an rx550 card. I added the Oibaf repos after the amd ones, and received updates from both. I say until recently because at some point opengl broke with this setup when using openshot and hugin leading to crashes. Removing everything sourced from oibaf in synaptic, then the repositories, then uninstalling and installing a newly downloaded amdgpu install fixed it. To be honest I'm happy to forego the daily updates, and if your setup is  working better than before, why mess with it? If you have used the all open setup for you will eventually get the mesa updates anyway.
I described this at length in an openshot bug report on [gitub](https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/5181) (though it was a graphics driver fault).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me which were the exact options when using `amdgpu-install` ? (`amdgpu-install --usecase=xyz --opencl=…`)

Comment: The last post on github  shows my working. I added components iteratively to test them which is not perhaps ideal, and I think my card needed the legacy opencl drivers, yours may be different. I think it amounted to `$ amdgpu-install --opencl=legacy` (speciying no --usecase option defaults to the dkms,graphics,opencl,hip options. That's the all open version. Actually, looking at it now, I probably don't even need to specify the opencl type.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me. Installing the AMD drivers after the Oibaf ones works fine, but the system will just use AMD's version of Mesa and not Oibaf's. Installing Oibaf's drivers _after_ the AMD ones, however, is not possible. About half of the drivers are being "kept back" by `apt-get upgrade` and trying to resolve the underlying dependency mess will likely brake my system (eg. by removing _ubuntu-desktop_ and such)… I guess I will just stick with AMD's official drivers and forget about Oibaf's.